# Office dialog window does not open on IE11

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We use the OfficeJS dialog window in an Outlook add-in [1].The location opened in the dialog window is under the same domain as the app used for the add-in. This is working on both OWA and Desktop clients. However, we have one user who is on Outlook 2016 and using the IE11 WebView that is getting the following error:

Desktop (Windows - Outlook 2016)

```
{
"code": 7000,
"message": "You don't have sufficient permissions for this action",
"name": "Permission Denied"
}
```

When accessing OWA on the user's IE11 browser we get a warning saying that dialog cannot be opened as the site is not in the same Security Zone as the OWA. In this case we can add our add-in to the list of Trusted Sites. This setting does not seem to make a difference to the desktop client.

The 7000 error code is not documented in [1]. Why is Outlook add-in WebView not honoring the Trusted Sites?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#errors-and-events-in-the-dialog-window

Comment: Can you provide us with the version number for Outlook?

Comment: IE: 11.0.165

Once again this is only happen to one user.

Comment: This looks like a version number associated with the browser. You can find the Outlook version by going to File -> Office Account -> look under the title of the About Outlook section.

Comment: Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO 16.0.4266.1001

Comment: No answer in 7 months? @SameeraJayaseckara did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: Yea, it was due to a missing patch described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451242/outlook-add-in-on-2016-proplus-msi-version-mso-16-0-4549-1000-gives-permissio?rq=1